# Prevent interaction to other elements when causing layout changes via touchstart

Tags: javascript, html

If you add an event listener for `touchstart` (on touch enabled devices) on an element in order to then hide said element - and another clickable item happens to be behind that element, then the touch interaction will still interact with the elements behind it. See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/86we1uxt/

If you run this fiddle on a touch enabled device - or just simulate it in your browser's developer tools - and click on "Click me!", the "Click me!" overlay will be hidden (set to `display: none`) via a `touchstart` event listener. However, the touch interaction will then still be in effect for whatever is behind that overlay, which is in this case a `<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">` and the browser will open that link.

Is there any way to prevent this? I would like to use `touchstart` instead of `click` for certain interactions, so that they will execute immediately. But I haven't figured out a way yet how to deal with this problem. Essentially this is a problem whenever a `touchstart` event changes the layout in some way, so that once the `touchstart` event is executed, something else might be "behind the users finger".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may be a solution:

```
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

overlay.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    this.style.opacity = '0';
});

overlay.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

or a more universal one:

```
document.querySelector('.overlay').addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
  touchLock = true;
  this.style.display = 'none';
});

let touchLock;
addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
  if (!touchLock)
    return;
  touchLock = null;
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}, true);
```

Comment: Seems overly complicated. But it's not just related to hiding elements. Consider this example: https://jsfiddle.net/70kp92fy/ - when touching "Show more" two additional link elements are shown right before the "Show more" button. But this also executes a click on the newly shown links.

Comment: there are no easy ways :), I updated my answer

Comment: Hm, I tried your way, but that still does not prevent the touch interaction beneath the original event: https://jsfiddle.net/terwnpad/1/

Comment: @fritzmg sure, because you have a typo `if (!touchLock) {l`

Comment: two typos in fact, considering variable declaration, you should fix it like this: `if (!touchlock) {`

Comment: Ah, silly me, thank you :). That would work, yes.